# SQL Server Best match query with update (T-SQL)

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I am trying to find out what's the most optimized SQL Query to achieve the following.

I have a table containing ZipCodes/PostalCodes, let's assume the following structure:

table_codes:

```
ID   |  ZipCode
---------------
1       1234
2       1235
3       456
```

and so on.

The users of my application fill up a profile where they are required to enter their ZipCode (PostalCode).
Assuming that sometimes, the user will enter a ZipCode not defined in my table, I am trying to suggest a Best Match based on the zip entered by the user.

I am using the following query:

```
Declare @entered_zipcode varchar(10)
set @entered_zipcode = '23456'


SELECT TOP 1 table_codes.ZipCode
FROM    table_codes
where   @entered_zipcode  LIKE table_codes.ZipCode + '%'
or table_codes.ZipCode + '%' like @entered_zipcode  + '%'
ORDER BY table_codes.ZipCode, LEN(table_codes.ZipCode) DESC
```

Basically, I am trying the following:

- if the @entered_zipcode is longer than any zip code in the table, I am trying to get to get the best prefix in the zip table matching the @entered_zipcode
- if the @entered_zipcode is shorter than any existing code in the table, I am trying to use it as a prefix and get the best match in the table

Moreover, I am building a temp table with the following structure:

```
#tmpTable
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
ID | user1_enteredzip | user1_bestmatchzip | user2_enteredzip | user2_bestmatchzip |
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
1  |   12             |     *1234*         |       4567       |       **456**      |
2  |
3  |
4  |
```

Entered zip is the one the user enters and the code between * .. * is the best matching code from my lookup table, that I am trying to get using the query below.

The query seems to take a little bit to long and this is why I am asking for help in optimizing it:

```
        update  #tmpTable
        set     user1_bestmatchzip = ( SELECT TOP 1
                                            zipcode
                                    FROM    table_codes
                                    where   #tmpTable.user1_enteredzip  LIKE table_codes.zipcode + '%'
                                            or table_codes.zipcode + '%' like #tmpTable.user1_enteredzip + '%'
                                    ORDER BY table_codes.zipcode, LEN(table_codes.zipcode) DESC
                                  ),
                user2_bestmatchzip = ( SELECT TOP 1
                                            zipcode
                                    FROM    table_codes
                                    where   #tmpTable.user2_enteredzip  LIKE table_codes.zipcode + '%'
                                            or table_codes.zipcode + '%' like #tmpTable.user2_enteredzip + '%'
                                    ORDER BY table_codes.zipcode, LEN(table_codes.zipcode) DESC
                                  )
         from #tmpTable
```

Comment: why are you using the temp table?

Comment: I am trying to do some computation with that temp table. What I wanted to show is that I need to get best matching zip for 2 columns in one update operations. It seems to me that my query is not the most optimal way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What if you change your temp table to be like:

```
id  |  user | enteredzip | bestmatchzip 
10  |  1    | 12345      | 12345
20  |  2    | 12         | 12345
```

That is: use a column to save the user number (1 or 2). This way you will update one row at a time.

Also, the `ORDER BY` takes time, did you set indices on the zipcode? Couldn't you create a field "length" in the zipcodes table to pre-compute the zipcodes lenghts?

**EDIT:**
I was thinking that ordering by LEN makes no sense, you could remove that! If the zipcodes cannot have duplicates, then ordering by the zipcode is just enought. If they can though, the `LEN` will always be equal!

Comment: Thank you vulkanino. I have an Index on ZipColumn, but the Length field sounds like a great ideea. I am going to try this and get back with results. Thank you very much.

Comment: The pre-computed "zip len" helped a bit in reducing the execution time, but not that much. I am considering the other approach you suggested.

Comment: Oau. Vulkanino, you are really good. I didn't thought about this, but you are absolutely right. Ordering by Len makes no sense. I just removed the clause, and the execution time is 3-4 times shorter now. From 700ms to ~200. You rock!

Answer (score 1):

You are comparing first characters of both strings - what if you compare substrings of minimal length?

```
select top 1 zipcode
from table_zipcodes
where substring(zipcode, 1, case when len(zipcode) > len (@entered_zipcode) then len(@entered_zipcode) else len (zipcode) end) 
    = substring (@entered_zipcode, 1, case when len(zipcode) > len (@entered_zipcode) then len(@entered_zipcode) else len (zipcode) end) 
order by len (zipcode) desc
```

This will remove OR and allow for usage of index *in_@entered_zipcode  LIKE table_codes.ZipCode + '%'*. Also, it seems to me that the ordering of results is wrong - shorter zipcodes go first.

Comment: Thank you Nikola for your answer. I tried your aproach as well, but the execution time doubles comparing to my current query. (that is my original query without the ORDER by len clause as suggested by Vulkanino)